# How to remove unwanted white gaps in html design using an html tabe?

Tags: html, html-table, master-pages

I am creating a website, but so far I have gaps in the design of my website, which is not wanted, as I do not what have any gaps between each of the blocks (for example I don't want any white spaces around the nav bar// black rectangle). I'm using an HTML table for the masterpage to create my website, and so far there are little white gaps in between each cell. I want to get rid off it, but I am unsure how. I wasn't sure if I had to add a CSS to it, but i'm still quite new html and coding in general.

Here's my coding

```
<table style="width:100%"; cellpadding="0"; cellpacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #869d92" ;class="auto-style1" rowspan="4" class="auto-style1">f</td>
                <td style="background-color:  #e9e9e9; height:150px">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphh_header" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: #869d92";class="auto-style1" rowspan="4">f</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:black; height:1.7cm">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphh_nav" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:white; height:1307px">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cph_main" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #7a7a7a;height:4.82cm">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphfooter" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: HTML respects whitespace between elements in the code. It might help if you delete the spaces between the cells

Answer (score 0):

To remove all white space in the table area, use `border-collapse: collapse;`. To remove all the white space around your website, use `margin: 0;`. Here would be a rudimentary stylesheet:

```
body {   margin: 0;   }
table {   border-collapse: collapse;   }
```